# How to split a line into words separated by one or more spaces in bash?

Tags: bash

I realize how to do it in python, just with

```
line = db_file.readline()
ll=string.split(line)
```

but how can I do the same in bash? is it really possible to do it in a so simple way?

Comment: I think you mean `ll=str.split(line)` in Python.

Answer (score 154):

```
s='foo bar baz'
a=( $s )
echo ${a[0]}
echo ${a[1]}
...
```

Comment: Inline variant: BAR="$(a=($value);echo ${a[1]})"

Comment: This gives a error  

./deploy.sh: 7: ./deploy.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected  
  
Line 7 is where,

a=( $s )

is located.

Comment: @isuru-buddhika This syntax is specific to Bash; you'll get that syntax error if your script is executed by something other than Bash (e.g. starts with `#!/bin/sh` on a Debian or Ubuntu system).  It should work if the script is executed like `bash deploy.sh` or the first line is changed to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`).

Comment: (I cannot add an answer to the question, hence adding as a comment)  


If you just want to extract the first or last word from (eg) output from a command, you can simply use the shell variable string substitution operators, to remove the first or last section of a string.  

    `desktop:~$ var="first last"
    desktop:~$ first_word=${var%% *} # space star !
    desktop:~$ echo $first_word   
    first
    desktop:~$ last_word=${var##* } # star space !
    desktop:~$ echo $last_word
    last`

Comment: This fails if the input has wildcard characters, e.g. place of `s='foo bar baz'` try `s='* bar baz'`

Answer (score 52):

If you want a specific word from the line, awk might be useful, e.g.

```
$ echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}'
```

Prints the second whitespace separated word in $LINE. You can also split on other characters, e.g.

```
$ echo "5:6:7" | awk -F: '{print $2}'
6
```

Comment: This is my reason to start using awk just now. Unlike array creation and extra lines. -F: does just explode from : in one just line. Love it, thx.

Comment: furthermore: `echo "5::6:7" | awk -F:: '{print $2}'`
`6:7`   (differently from cut, that takes only one char as delimiter)

Answer (score 42):

It depends upon what you mean by *split*.  If you want to iterate over words in a line, which is in a variable, you can just iterate.  For example, let's say the variable `line` is `this is a line`.  Then you can do this:

```
for word in $line; do echo $word; done
```

This will print:

```
this
is
a
line
```

`for .. in $var` splits `$var` using the values in `$IFS`, the default value of which means "split blanks and newlines".

If you want to read lines from user or a file, you can do something like:

```
cat $filename | while read line
do
    echo "Processing new line" >/dev/tty
    for word in $line
    do
        echo $word
    done
done
```

For anything else, you need to be more explicit and define your question in more detail.

*Note*: Edited to remove bashism, but I still kept `cat $filename | ...` because I like it more than redirection.

Comment: Useless use of `cat` - redirect the file like this: `done < "$filename"`. Also, use `for value in "${var[@]}"` in this context instead of an index variable. While in this case the array may be contiguous, Bash supports sparse arrays and `${#var[@]}` may not be the last entry (although `${var[@]: -1}` will be and `indices=(${!a[@]}); count=${#indices[@]}` will give the list of indices and the correct count)

Comment: @Dennis: All good points. I am used to `cat a | blah` instead of `blah <a' for some reason; but other points are well-taken.

Comment: This approach will fail if you've good an asterisk (*) in the $line. Bash will substitute if with the file list in the current directory.

Answer (score 41):

```
echo $line | tr " " "\n"
```

gives the output similar to those of most of the answers above; without using loops.

In your case, you also mention `ll=<...output...>`,

so, (given that I don't know much python and assuming you need to assign output to a variable),

```
ll=`echo $line | tr " " "\n"`
```

should suffice (remember to `echo "$ll"` instead of `echo $ll`)

Answer (score 13):

More simple,

```
echo $line | sed 's/\s/\n/g'
```

> \s --> whitespace character (space, tab, NL, FF, VT, CR). In many
>   systems also valid [:space:]
>
> \n --> new line

Comment: This will turn each individual space character into its own newline, right?

Answer (score 12):

do this

```
while read -r line
do
  set -- $line
  echo "$1 $2"
done <"file"
```

$1, $2 etc will be your 1st and 2nd splitted "fields". use $@ to get all values..use $# to get length of the "fields".

Comment: Note that if your `$line` contains e.g. `*`, this will get expanded by bash when doing `set -- $line`, which can have surprising effects.

Comment: 1) What does the "--" do?

2) What surprising effects can expanding * have?

Answer (score 10):

```
$ line="these are words"
$ ll=($line)
$ declare -p ll  # dump the array
declare -a ll='([0]="these" [1]="are" [2]="words")'
$ for w in ${ll[@]}; do echo $w; done
these
are
words
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me the -p option

Answer (score 6):

The `-a` option of [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) will allow you to split a line read in by the characters contained in `$IFS`.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

filename=$1


while read LINE
do
 echo $LINE |  read -a
done < $filename


should it work?

Comment: No, -a would be an argument to the first read. "help read" at a bash command line will, uh... help.

Comment: @asdf: It would look like this: `filename=$1; while read -a LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < "$filename"`

Answer (score 4):

If you already have your line of text in a variable $LINE, then you should be able to say

```
for L in $LINE; do
   echo $L;
done
```