# Bash: Split text-file into words with non-alphanumeric characters as delimiters

Tags: parsing, bash, scripting

Lets say "*textfile*" contains the following:

```
lorem$ipsum-is9simply the.dummy text%of-printing
```

and that you want to print each word on a separate line. ***However***, words should be defined not only by spaces, but by all non-alphanumeric characters. So the results should look like:

```
 lorem
 ipsum  
 is9simply  
 the  
 dummy  
 text  
 of  
 printing
```

**How can I accomplish this using the Bash shell?**

---

Some notes:

- *This is not a homework question.*
- *The simpler case when the words should be determined only by spaces, is easy. Just writing*:

  ```
  for i in `cat textfile`; do echo $i; done;
  ```

  *will do the trick, and return:*

  ```
   lorem$ipsum-is9simply
   the.dummy
   text%of-printing
  ```

  *For splitting words by non-alphanumeric characters I have seen solutions that use the IFS environmental variable (links below), but I would like to avoid using IFS for two reasons: 1) it would require (I think) setting the IFS to a long list of non-alphanumeric characters. 2) I find it kind of ugly.*
- *Here are the two related Q&As I found*
  [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash)
  [How to split a line into words separated by one or more spaces in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975849/split-line-into-words-in-bash)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [tr](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) command:

```
tr -cs 'a-zA-Z0-9' '\n' <textfile
```

The '`-c`' is for the complement of the specified characters; the '`-s`' squeezes out duplicates of the replacements; the `'a-zA-Z0-9'` is the set of alphanumeric characters (maybe add `_` too?); the '\n' is the replacement character (newline).  You could also use a character class which is locale sensitive (and may include more characters than the list above):

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '\n' <textfile
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was after. Thanks!
(I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer)

Comment: @Sv1: You will probably have a high reputation soon.  I voted your question up because of how well you documented what you wanted and for all the research you had done on it.

Comment: What if you have decimal numbers?

Comment: @Leyu: add the extra characters to the set that is retained: `tr -cs '[:alnum:]+-.' '\n' < textfile`.  Of course, that will allow through full stops and ellipsis and dashed lines, etc.  But it will also allow through +1.23 and -1.24e-23, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -f splitter.awk < textfile

$ cat splitter.awk
{
  count0 = split($0, asplit, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
  for(i = 1; i <= count0; ++i) { print asplit[i] }
}
```

Comment: thanks Ross! this is pretty cool, I've been meaning to get into the awk-universe :)