# Shell Programming: Access Element of List

Tags: string, list, shell, indexing

It is my understanding that when writing a Unix shell program you can iterate through a string like a list with a for loop. Does this mean you can access elements of the string by their index as well?

For example:

```
foo="fruit vegetable bread"
```

How could I access the first word of this sentence? I've tried using brackets like the C-based languages to no avail, and solutions I've read online require regular expressions, which I would like to avoid for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `$foo` as argument to a function. Than you can use `$1`, `$2` and so on to access the corresponding word in the function.

```
function try {
 echo $1
}

a="one two three"

try $a
```

EDIT: another better version is:

```
a="one two three"
b=( $a )
echo ${b[0]}
```

EDIT(2): have a look at [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975849/split-line-into-words-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays  is the best solution.

Here's a tricky way using indirect variables

```
get() { local idx=${!#}; echo "${!idx}"; }

foo="one two three"

get $foo 1  # one
get $foo 2  # two
get $foo 3  # three
```

Notes:

- `$#` is the number of parameters given to the function (4 in all these cases)
- `${!#}` is the *value* of the last parameter
- `${!idx}` is the *value* of the `idx`'th parameter
- You must not quote `$foo` so the shell can split the string into words.

With a bit of error checking:

```
get() {
  local idx=${!#}
  if (( $idx < 1 || $idx >= $# )); then
    echo "index out of bounds" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo "${!idx}"
}
```

Please don't actually use this function. Use an array.